# PHP Compare Two Variables Results In "stdClass could not be converted to int"

Tags: php, apache-flex

I am trying to use a simple compare function of the results of a MySQLi database query but I keep getting "stdClass could not be converted to int" for the following code snippet:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "SELECT access_user_id, failed_login_count FROM $this->accesstable where username=?");
            $this->throwExceptionOnError();

            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $trimmedUsername);       
            $this->throwExceptionOnError();

            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $this->throwExceptionOnError();

            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $user_id->access_user_id, $failed_login_count->failed_login_count);

            $failed_login_count = (int)$failed_login_count;

            if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {

                if($failed_login_count < 10) {
```

The very last line there is what throws the error... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $failed_login_count->failed_login_count, this is an object it is writen above try to use the same in your test

Comment: you convert class to integer `$failed_login_count = (int)$failed_login_count;` but maybe you should do `$failed_login_count = $failed_login_count->failed_login_count;`

Comment: well, that cleared up the execution problems, however, the "if($failed_login_count < 10)" is still evaluates to false even though the database value is 21...